# Batch Scripting Language; start url with double quotes

Tags: batch-file, url, quotes, google-search, double-quotes

I am trying to write a batch script that starts a google search for e.g "Sun Moon Lake" in double quotes.
However, the double quotes are not appearing.

My script is as follows :

```
@echo off
start https://www.google.com/search?q="Sun+moon+lake"
```

[image: Search bar not showing double quotes]

Thanks!

Comment: Try `start "Window Title" https...`  `start` assumes the first `"quoted string"` in the parameters is a window-title.

Comment: I would suggest, from a batch-file: `@Start "" "https://www.google.com/search?q=%%22Sun+moon+lake%%22"`, or from cmd: `Start "" "https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Sun+moon+lake%22"`

Comment: Awesome guys! The recommendations worked perfectly, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try start "Window Title" https... start assumes the first "quoted string" in the parameters is a window-title. – Magoo

I would suggest, from a batch-file: @Start "" "https://www.google.com/search?q=%%22Sun+moon+lake%%22", or from cmd: Start "" "https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Sun+moon+lake%22" – Compo

The above works fine and I want to put a closure to this question.